# lifting a product of commutators of standard generators on 2-manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces

I have a problem with understand the proof http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-032-01/S0002-9939-1972-0295352-2/S0002-9939-1972-0295352-2.pdf

I don't understand this part: "(...) we can easily construct $p: \tilde{F} \rightarrow F$ to be a six sheeted covering corresponding to the kernel of an appropriate map $\pi_1(F) \rightarrow \Sigma_3$ (such covering that: if $f$ represents a loop without sef-intersections and which is a product of commutators of "standard generators" then $f$ does not lift to a loop in $\tilde{F}$)."

$\hspace{1.5cm}$ 1. why we know that such covering exist?

$\hspace{1.5cm}$ 2. why this covering is  six sheeted?

$\hspace{1.5cm}$ 3. why kernel doesn't contain $f$?

Answer (score 4):

Justin Malestein and I give a very explicit construction of such a cover in the proof of Lemma 2.1 of our paper

Malestein, Justin, Putman, Andrew;
On the self-intersections of curves deep in the lower central series of a surface group.
Geom. Dedicata 149 (2010), 73–84.

which is available [here](http://www.math.rice.edu/~andyp/papers/SelfIntersections.pdf).  We actually construct an $8$-fold cover instead of a $6$-fold cover because it was important for us that the deck group be nilpotent (in this case, a $2$-group).  This was needed because our paper (among other things) was generalizing Hempel's argument to show that surface groups were residually nilpotent.  But the $8$-fold cover we construct is good enough to make Hempel's argument go through (and in any case once you see what is happening you'll have no problem finding the $6$-fold cover if that is what you really want).

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I have some new questions to your proof: 

1. why always there is a surjection $\phi': H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi'(\phi(x))\neq 0$ (for example when we have $\alpha_1^7 \beta_1$ it belongs to $H_1(\Sigma; \mathbb{Z})$ and I think it goes to 0)? Could you explain how look the surjection $\phi'$

Comment: 2.I could believe that $\pi_1(\Sigma,*)= \langle  \alpha_1,\beta_1,...,\alpha_g,\beta_g,x_1,...,x_g \mid [\alpha_1,\beta_1] \cdots [\alpha_g,\beta_g] = x_1 \cdots x_b \rangle $ but I have little experience in algebraic topology so I would like to see a proof of this fact. Could you tell me where I can read about it or could you explain this.

Comment: 3.I think I found a small mistakes at the end of "case 1". In one place there is : "$x \notin \{\alpha_1,\beta_1,\alpha_g,\beta_g\}$" and later there is "$s \notin \{\alpha_1,\beta_1,\alpha_g,\beta_g\}$" - I guess in the first place there should be $s$ instead of $x$, but in the second " $s \notin \{\alpha_1,\beta_1\}$"  am I right?

Comment: @FilipParker : 1. The surjection depends on $x$; for example, if you are dealing with $\alpha_1^7 \beta_1$ then you choose the homomorphism that takes $[\alpha_i]$ to $0$ for all $i$, that takes $[\beta_i]$ to $0$ for all $i \neq 1$, and that takes $[\beta_1]$ to $1$.  2.  There are 2 points here.  The first is that this is a presentation for $\pi_1$ of a punctured surface, which is discussed in any book that deals with surfaces and the fundamental group (e.g. Massey's book on the fundamental group).  (continued)

Comment: (continued) The second is that the surface is of this form.  This can be derived from the classification of surfaces.  I recommend perusing Section 1.3 of Farb-Margalit's "Primer on mapping class groups" for the details.  3. You are correct that these are typos; thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: in your proof you say that: for normal covers, loop $f$ lifts to a closed curve if and only if any curve freely homotopic to $f$ lifts to a closed curve. Do we have to assume that cover is normal? I think for any cover it is true since covering spaces has homotopy lifting property

Comment: @FilipParker : The homotopy lifting property tells you that that a loop $f$ lifts to a closed curve if and only if any curve which is homotopic to $f$ while fixing the base point lifts to a closed curve.  Freely homotoping the curve lets the base point move, and thus corresponds to conjugating $f$.

Comment: ok, so could you prove or say where I can find a proof of this fact for normal covers?

Comment: @FilipParker : My last comment constitutes a complete proof.  If you don't understand it, I recommend meditating on the part of any book on algebraic topology that discusses changing the base point in the fundamental group.  I remember Massey's book having a particularly nice treatment of this.

Comment: oh yes, I missed it

Comment: I have one more question: In this lemma (2.1) you say -"By the remark following the lemma, we may assume without loss of generality that $f$ is an immersion whose singularities consist of $i(f)$ isolated double points". Can you explain why we can always find a (freely) homotopic closed curve with finitely many points of intersection?

Comment: @FilipParker : Fix a piecewise-linear structure on your surface and homotope the curve such that it is piecewise-linear (this is trivial; just fix a bunch of points on it and "pull them tight").  Then jiggle the vertices a little so that all of the line segments in your curve intersect transversely.

Comment: I will be grateful, if you want to explain me, why you wrote:" if $f$ is nullhomologous then there is a generating set $S$ for $\pi_1(\Sigma, *)$ such that $x=[\alpha_1,\beta_1]\cdots[\alpha_{g'}, \beta_{g'}]$ for some $g' \le g$". I know Hurewicz theorem (so I know that $x$ belongs to comutant of fundamental group), but I don't understand why in this representation of $x$ there is no components of the form $[x_i, \beta_j]$ or $[\alpha_i. \beta_j]$ etc.?

Comment: Is this lemma is true for surfaces with abelian fundamental group? Because i think that your proof is also good for this kind of surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

I think that talking about "products of commutators" is not useful (probably the fashion of the time was more algebraic). Cut along your null-homologous curve, so you get two pieces each with one boundary component, and restrict your attention to one of these (say, $S_1$). You want to find a nontrivial covering of $S_1$ with a single boundary component (which will be of length a multiple of the original boundary). You can then verify Hempel's claim by some educational cutting and pasting.